How to make polynomials with so many exponents and variables within said terms easier to solve
Look guys, I want to level with you. I am reaching the end of my 4th-5th algebra 1 or MAT 101 class in college, and this is one of the classes I need to graduate altogether so it, in of itself, is both satisfying and yet, terrifying, since it could LITERALLY be this year that I graduate college. I merely have Algebra 1, Probability and Statistics (The second is one class rather than two), and some electives and I'm done. Perhaps some of you can understand where I am coming from. I started college in 2018 and if I'm honest....I have never been a math person. I want to be, but I am not. And I know I am not the only one. So much so that after a few failures in algebra, I chose to put all math to the end. I took Math 155 which is like a quick beginner's course and got through with an 80, and then went into Algebra 1. I failed, and now am taking it again. Since I started, I have been working my butt off in class, in spite of things on my end not necessarily being what I feel they should be. But I am struggling to no end with these multiple term polynomials. Polynomials like (-10t^5+9t^4-3t^3+2t+11) + (-6-3t-3t^2+3t^3+3t^5) for example. Its like the more variables and the more exponents in each set of terms, the more likely my brain is to shut off. Perhaps not just my mind but the minds of others as well may deal with the same issue. What can I and others like myself do?  Because I can tell that these kind of questions will be on the final and will probably what costs me and forces me to redo algebra 1 for the 6th time. And I for one am sick to death of algebra. I want to understand what I am doing so that I can actually manage on the test, at least for a 70. And I cannot be the only one, surely someone else around here is struggling with this too correct? Is that not why we reach out here on the Mathematics Stack Exchange, to seek help and to help each other?

Depends upon what you're trying to do. Like solve what? Give an example question in this post, which you're unable to do.

Lemme see here.... how about (-3w^5-2w+7)-(7w^4-10w^3+w+4)+(6w^3+w+8)? I look at a problem like this and its like my mind goes blank immediately.

I have read your syllabus. Regarding the doubt in your replies,
first multiply all the (-) and (+) with the terms inside the brackets to get a fully expanded polynomial.
$$(-3w^5-2w+7)-(7w^4-10w^3+w+4)+(6w^3+w+8)=-3w^5-2w+7-7w^4+10w^3-w-4+6w^3+w+8$$
Then group the values having same degrees of $w$.
$$=-3w^5-7w^4+(10+6)w^3+(-2-1+1)w+(7-4+8)$$
Finally add them
$$=-3w^5-7w^4+16w^3-2w+11$$
I also saw that you have factoring in your syllabus. It's mainly comprising of quadratic functions. Do you need help regarding that too?

I could most difinitely use some, thank you so much! :)

Hey @YourLordJoyBoy one more thing. Do you find factoring this x²-7x+12 easy or hard?

I'm thinking hard since I've been working so much on the polynomials the last couple days.

I think 5 mins is enough for your thoughts. Did you get any answers

(x−4)(x−3) But I think once I've got a handle on these polynomials I'm gonna go back into factoring. I'm gonna need to know it to get that too, and seriously @Gwen thank you.

Wait a moment @YourLordJoyBoy I can maybe try to open a chatroom

Looks like I need a reputation of 20 in order to chat.

Sadly I don't know how to :") I'm trying to figure out @YourLordJoyBoy

@YourLordJoyBoy https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/152610/random-discussion-between-luffy-and-me

My reputation has to be higher it seems. Cause I tried to do it and it said my rep is too low.

Reddit/Discord acc? @YourLordJoyBoy

Oh yeah that's doable. its thegothamninja (discord)

@YourLordJoyBoy done check once

Wait, you also mentioned redit right? I think we might have to do that instead.

YourLord1989
u/YourLord1989 And sorry bout the wait. Trying to make sure it doesn't look to my stepmom that I'm goofing off.

@YourLordJoyBoy sent a hi please check

Unfortunately, the chat room you made is gone. And I don't have a high enough reputation to make a new one.

@YourLordJoyBoy hey hey hey I'm here

Ugh we keep missing each other.

@YourLordJoyBoy I don't think so :)

YES, YOU'RE HERE! :D I'm so sorry this took so long.

@YourLordJoyBoy not a problem. How are you doing? I was busy in somthing else but I saw your message

Good, but we should continue this in our chat.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@YourLordJoyBoy better log on to reddit.

I logged into both, you must be busy.

@YourLordJoyBoy    Yes I am actually

Its cool. Just respond when you're able.

Reddit is down, lets go to the chat to continue the tutoring in factoring

Hey sup, can you chat now? @YourLordJoyBoy?

It works now, that was so weird!
